# Vue's "Component which was made a reactive object" Warning

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-reactivity

I've written a component using the `defineComponent` syntax, with a template, like this:

```js
<script>
import MySvgComponent from './MySvgComponent.vue'
const MyComponent = defineComponent({
  components: {
    MySvgComponent
  },
  template: `
    <div><MySvgComponent /></div>
  `,
})
</script>
```

For some reason, when I do this, I get the following warning:

"Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of `ref`"

The solution here is to wrap the imported component in either markRaw or shallowRef, which resolves the warning, like this:

```js
<script>
import { markRaw } from 'vue'
import MySvgComponent from './MySvgComponent.vue'
const MyRawSvgComponent = markRaw(MySvgComponent);
const MyComponent = defineComponent({
  components: {
    MyRawSvgComponent
  },
  template: `
    <div><MyRawSvgComponent /></div>
  `,
})
</script>
```

Why does this resolve the warning?

It looks like based on the documentation that wrapping a Javascript object in `markRaw` returns a non-proxied version of the original object. Why do we need to do that here, and what exactly is the performance issue going on here that we're resolving by using the `markRaw` or `shallowRef` functions?